# Tool to create validation functions for TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working with an existing codebase that I'm introducting TypeScript too.

say I've got some frontend code that looks like this:

```
const res = await fetch('/api/user'); 
const user = res.json();
```

And my User interface looks like:

```
interface User {
    name: string; 
    age; 
}
```

I could just coerce the response from .json()

```
const user = res.json() as User;
```

But there is no guarantee that the backend is actually sending me the correct response and I'd rather be aware of that upfront. So my preference is to use a parsing function like:

```
function parseUser(input: any) : User {
    try {
        const user = {
           name: input.name, 
           age: input.age
        }; 

        if (typeof user.name !== 'string' || typeof user.age !== 'number') {
             throw new Error("Object had correct field, but wrong value types"); 
        }
        return user; 
    } catch(err) {
         throw new Error("Error parsing user"); 
    }
}
```

Now the thing is - for objects with much larger schemas, this would be hellish to write.

Is there some kind of utilty that can create these functions from my interface definitions?

Comment: The answer looks like it's in these threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800497/check-if-an-object-implements-an-interface-at-runtime-with-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ts-interface-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-interface-builder) and [ts-interface-checker](https://github.com/gristlabs/ts-interface-checker) libraries work very well for this. Here's how I set mine up:

**One important downside** is that this does not support generics, except for unwrapping promises.

**1. Add the dependencies as dev dependencies**

```
npm i -D ts-interface-builder ts-interface-checker
```

**2.Define your types in `src/types`**

```
//src/types/User.ts

export interface User {
    name: string; 
    age; 
}
```

**3. Add a `src/ti` folder**

The next step will fail if this folder doesn't already exist.

**4. Add `buildCheckers` npm script**

```
//package.json 

    "buildCheckers": "ts-interface-builder -o src/ti src/types/*.ts",
```

**5. To create a new parsing function:**

1. run `npm run buildCheckers` (I don't know how to get this command to run in watch mode).
2. Create a parsing function as follows, (I put the parsing function in the same file as the interface definition)

```
//src/types/User.ts
import userTypes from "../ti/User-ti";
const {  User} = createCheckers(userTypes);

//Our existing interface we created in step 2
export interface User {
    name: string; 
    age; 
}

export function parseUser(item: any): User {
    try {
        User.check(item); 
        return item as User;
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error ("Error instantiating object to type User"); 
    }
}
```